# Delay in pause video on headset removal

Tags: android, video, headset

I am playing video and trying to pause it when headset is removed. But unfortunately there is a time delay of about 1-2 sec after which music/video gets stopped. The same piece of code works fine when I use it for a music player but not for a video player. Can anyone help?

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Register headset receiver
    registerReceiver(headsetReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));}


// If headset gets unplugged, stop music and service.
private final BroadcastReceiver headsetReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    private boolean headsetConnected = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Log.v("TAG", "ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG Intent received");
        if (intent.hasExtra("state")) {
            if (headsetConnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 0) {
                headsetConnected = false;
                headsetSwitch = 0;

            } else if (!headsetConnected
                    && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1) {
                headsetConnected = true;
                headsetSwitch = 1;

            }

        }

        switch (headsetSwitch) {
            case (0):
                headsetDisconnected();
                break;
            case (1):
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

};

private void headsetDisconnected() {
    if(videoInterface!=null)
        videoInterface.stopVideo();

}
```

Fragment :

```
public class VideoPlayerFragment extends Fragment implements VideoInterface
{
 @Override
 public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((VideoPlayer)getActivity()).videoInterface = this;
}
 @Override
 public void stopVideo() {   // interface method
    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
       mediaPlayer.pause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always rewind the video;

```
    int currTime = mediaplayer.getcurrentposition();
    int newTime = currTime - 3000; // 3k milliseconds
    mediaplayer.seekTo(newTime);
```

Comment: Why to rewind when I just need to pause? There must be a better solution there.

Comment: It may be just a slow response time(lag). I couldn't think of any thing else.

Comment: Its not just about the timing alone. If user removes headset , music should stop instantly. Your solution wont stop music from playing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using the below code. Reference : http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-output.html

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);

    registerReceiver(headsetReceiver, intentFilter);

// If headset gets unplugged, stop music and service.
private final BroadcastReceiver headsetReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // Pause the playback
            headsetDisconnected();
        }

        }

};

private void headsetDisconnected() {
    if(videoInterface!=null)
        videoInterface.stopVideo();

}
```